# VueJS : Can I use splice/push on a computed array?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, array-push, array-splice

I'm just wondering if I'm able to change a computed array programmatically.
In my case, I tried to splice an item to an array and push it to another position in an array.
lets say...

```
list_array = [{list_id: 1, status: 'good', data: {item_id: 1, event: 'jumping'}]
```

My splice and push code goes like this...

```
refreshList(event, api_data) {
    const remove_index = this.list_array.findIndex(list => list.list_id == event.list_id);
    const remove_data_index = this.list_array[remove_index].data.findIndex(data => data.item_id == event.item_id);

    this.list_array[remove_index].splice(remove_data_index, 1);

    const new_index = this.list_array.findIndex(list => list.list_id == api_data.list_id);
    if (new_index == -1) {
        this.list_array.push({
            list_id : api_data.list_id,
            status: api_data.status,
            data: api_data,
        })
    } else {
        this.list_array[new_index].data.push(api_data);
    }
}
```

Now, this code works... when I look at `list_array` in the Vue Console computed. the splicing and pushing seems to work... but the data rendering does not seem to change.

Comment: You need to go through [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) to understand why Vue might not be reactive to the changes you introduce to your state.

Answer (score 0):

When using arrays or maps, make sure they are initialized in  the data part of your component or they won't be reactive.

"computed" properties have get and set methods. You need to use the set method to change them.

Comment: I checked in the vue console, the `splice` and `push` seems to work tho, but the rendered items does not seem to change at all. btw, if I can't push, any idea how do I achieve what I want?

Comment: Have u initialized array in data?

Comment: You mean when I push it?, No i didn't. That one is also the what I observed that instead of `data: Array[1]`, it shows there, `data: Object`... but is it really a problem?

Comment: You need to initialize the array in data of the component. Read the article in kidA's comment.

Comment: I don't think computed property can be initialized in data

Comment: computed properties have get and set methods. You need to use that to change them.

Comment: That's not true. You can definitely push into an observable array and it will be updated accordingly.

Comment: @Terry I have changed the answer to make it more accurate.